# Basic Script for Zip after a file is processed

Tags: zip

Hi I need a few pointers,

i have a system that processes a file and then writes that file to a bunch of storage. I would like to write a simple bash script that I can run as a post processing script to Zip or tar the file once its done with output.

Could someone tell me how I could do this once the file is done ?